# Deploying to an Azure website

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am following this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/nodejs-deployment/deploy-website)....

Now I am finding the section about deploying to Azure a little ambiguous. So here is my question(s) which are not addressed in this document/article:

- Is it required to have the remote branch be called "Azure"?
- How does pushing from Azure branch to Master branch initiate the actual deployment?

If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'azure' is not the name of the branch, but the name of the **remote** (see [this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) if you're not familiar with the git remote concept). And you can choose to name the remote whatever you want.

As for how `git push azure master` causes a deployment, it is done because the repo on Azure has a `post-receive` hook which kicks the deployment. You can see this in Kudu console if you go to `D:\home\site\repository\.git\hooks`.

Comment: I am familiar with git concepts. Isn't a "Remote" simply a "remote branch" (vs a local branch that has been created or cloned)?

Comment: Regardless, how does the following command actually deploy to azure website? $ git push azure master

Comment: No, a remote is not a remote branch. A remote is an alias to a git url. The default git remote name is 'origin', and here we just use 'azure' as the remote name instead. Then for a given remote, you can have any number of branches.

Comment: Expanding on Davids point, when you push to the remote you set up called `azure` (hosted on Microsoft Azure), the Azure cloud knows to deploy your app from `master`. The `azure` remote is not really its own git repo, in that it doesn't provide source control, but instead it is an endpoint in the cloud that uses the git protocol to pull the latest commit from `master` and deploy to your Azure app service.

Comment: Now Dan Schnau, that's the answer i was looking for. You should write articles/documents for microsoft. My goodness they could use some good technical writers.

Comment: I added details on how the deployment starts. But note that you really had two distinct questions here: one about git remotes in general, and one about how a push starts a deployment. We have now covered both.